# Access UniformGrid ItemTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I'm trying to build a bingo game simulator using WPF to learn more about WPF, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to change an `<ItemsControl>` template programmatically.

I'm only using the default WPF Application from VS 2010, so I have a MainWindow.xaml, App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs.

The reason I want to access the `<ItemTemplate>`, is to change the bound template if that bingo number comes up as chosen.

I've tried [this possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/984862/1804496) in my code behind file, but I don't think that works in this situation.

Here is how I have my MainWindow and App xaml files set up

## MainWindow.xaml

```
<ItemsControl Name="icBColumn" ItemsSource="{Binding CardBNumbers}" 
              Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BingoSquare}"
              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource BingoColumn}">
```

## App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BingoSquare">
  <Border Background="{DynamicResource UnmarkedSquare}">
    <Label Content="{Binding}" />
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="UnmarkedSquare" GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                     Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
  <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStop Color="LimeGreen" Offset="1" />
  </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</RadialGradientBrush>
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="BingoColumn">
  <UniformGrid Name="NumbersGrid" Columns="1" Rows="5"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) there you will find code that is close enough to what you need but needs some work.

I would propose some recontruction.

For example you bind your ItemsControl's ItemsSource to CardBNumbers. Is it a list of int or a list of CustomClass e.g. BingoNumClass. If it is a custom class the add a boolean  IsBingo boolean property which you will by defualt turn to false. It will turn to true from your code whenever a bingo number is selected and you will update the items of CardBNumbers list.

Then you could extend your ItemTemplate with Datatriggers on IsBingo Property to Chnage its appearrence as soon as it is selected - turned to true from your CardBNumbers list.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't looked at that yet. I'll check it out and get back to you.

Comment: I was wondering earlier if what you added in your edit was something that was possible! I just had no idea exactly how. Currently CardBNumbers is a List<string>. So I'm thinking, like you said, just create a new class that will represent a bingo space, with string number property and bool checked property!

Comment: yes exaqctly that. implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and once the bool value is updated you can catch this event with xaml Style Datatriggers. if you want me to be more specific i can and i will but on monday. Cu!